# python json.dumps: unable to ignore non serializable objects

Tags: python, json

In python when i want to pretty print an object during debugging i use

```
print(json.dumps(obj.__dict__), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

because just using `print(obj)` is not very readable

Then if some of the items are non serialzable it says

```
Object of type SOMETHING is not JSON serializable
```

So my goal is to just check an object while debugging and not to have a perfectly serialized object to pass it and later convert back.

I tried the following by adding `default=str` to avoid the error and it worked in many cases

```
print(json.dumps(obj.__dict__), indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

But still in some cases it shows

```
Object of type SOMETHING is not JSON serializable
```

So how to solve this.

The object i am trying is from Django project. I am trying to pretty print using the help of `json.dumps`

```
from django.db import connections
import json
for c in connections.all():
    c_dict = {k: getattr(c, k) for k in dir(c)} # this gives all the properties listed using dir(c)
    print(json.dumps(c_dict), indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

**ANSWER:**

@milanbalanz answered it in the comments. Its a `typo error` of the brackets. So `default=str` works as its indented to
the wrong one is

```
print(json.dumps(c_dict), indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

the right one is

```
print(json.dumps(c_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
```

Comment: FYI, You parentheses are not correct. `print(json.dumps(obj.__dict__, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))`

Comment: @milanbalanzs You are right. thats why its not working, the mistake was  `print(json.dumps(c_dict), indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)` the right one is as you said `print(json.dumps(obj.__dict__, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))`. Wasted 4 -5 days on this

Comment: I am happy to helped. I have added an answer so you can mark answered your question if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The position of your parentheses are not correct.

**The correct line:**

```
print(json.dumps(obj.__dict__, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code, Hope this would help.

```
from json import JSONEncoder

class Encoder(JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            return o.__dict__ 

Encoder().encode(f)
```

Comment: i got this error `object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what kind of object you are using?

Comment: added an example